# Как изменить внешний вид CalendarView в андроид?

Tags: java, android

Как изменить внешний вид CalendarView в андроид?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый простой способ - использовать готовые библиотеки, которые позволяют кастомизировать внешний вид. Например

https://github.com/npanigrahy/Custom-Calendar-View

https://github.com/code-troopers/android-betterpickers